# Perl - closing curly bracket before the opening one. How does it work?

Tags: perl

I came across [this solution](https://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/5-ways-to-reverse-order-of-file-content.html) to reverse the content of a file :

```
$ cat f1
abc
def
ghi
jkl

$ perl -ne 'push @arr,$_;}{print reverse @arr;' f1
jkl
ghi
def
abc
```

Could someone please explain how the curly brackets work ? I'm confused, the closing bracket comes before the opening one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2212405/2072269 (also links to another example using apparently mismatched braces)

Comment: That's so called [Eskimo greeting](https://metacpan.org/dist/perlsecret/view/lib/perlsecret.pod#Eskimo-greeting).

Comment: Thanks. There's also that fine explanation (in the comments) : https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=130140

Comment: Where I come from, that's called the "colliding seagulls 'operator'".

Answer (score 5):

That's because the `-n` switch literally adds curly brackets around the source code. As the [manual](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#n) says:

> `-n`
> causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like `sed -n` or `awk`:
>
> ```
> LINE:
>   while (<>) {
>       ...             # your program goes here
>   }
> ```

This doesn't just mean that Perl will run an equivalent loop around the program. It actually adds the prefix and suffix shown here (with different spacing). Citing the source code (`toke.c`):

```
            if (PL_minus_n || PL_minus_p) {
                sv_catpvs(PL_linestr, "LINE: while (<>) {"/*}*/);
```

and

```
        } else if (!PL_in_eval && PL_minus_n) {
            sv_catpvs(linestr, /*{*/";}");
```

The function `sv_catpvs` appends the specified string to an intermediate buffer containing the source code to parse. I think a line break is also inserted before `;}` (since `#` in the `-e` string doesn't comment them out). Somewhere between those two calls, the content of `-e` is also appended.

Other switches like `-p`, `-F`, `-E`, etc. work similarly.

Thus your code example runs

```
LINE: while (<>) {push @arr,$_;}{print reverse @arr;;}
```

which, with proper spacing, is.

```
LINE: while (<>) {
    push @arr,$_;
}
{
    print reverse @arr;
    ;
}
```

Eliminating the unused label, the second group of braces (which is not necessary for grouping) and the empty instruction (lone `;`), that's:

```
while (<>) {
    push @arr,$_;
}
print reverse @arr;
```

The loop adds lines to `@arr` in order, and the instruction after the loop prints them in reverse order.